# Manually update Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) was released but my VS instance does not offer the update yet. How can I manually trigger an update?

Comment: Note that it depends on exactly when you did this. Since this is mostly controlled through cloud configuration, if you tried this just after the initial release, it might not update to anything newer than 15.3. The notification flag also might take a while to trigger. You can always manually download the "Free Trial" version of the installer for your SKU from the website, and it will update the version of the installer on your system to offer the [15.4 update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/10/11/windows-10-fall-creators-update-sdk/).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Launch the visual studio installer (hit the windows key and type the name, you'll find it). It will then ask you to allow it to update itself, after which you will be offered the update.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes even the Visual Studio Installer needs an update before.

Comment: Will it take the same time as a complete installation?

Comment: Depends. Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 8):

You can update it from Notifications Hub left side of Visual studio.

In Notification Hub/Pane click on **"Visual Studio Update" is available**.

Or You can also update it from Visual Studio Installer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio

Comment: For some reason the update does not appear (yet). Restarted multiple times over multiple days.

Comment: there is Visual Studio Installer link in answer that will allow you to update manually.

Comment: If you want to know the version to be installed, it is available as a mouse-over hint for the Update button.

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates

Comment: This is what I had to do to find the update for 15.0 -> 15.9. It prompted me to update my installer (which I couldn't find), which it did for me, then installed the VS update.

Answer (score 2):

**To update the core** , let say from 15.4  > 15.9 , you need launch Visual Studio then
Help > Check for updates

[image]

**To add\remove\update other sub component** , you will need to run the Visual Studio installer and pick the require option.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this… some of our build machines got an update offered through the Visual Studio Installer, others didn't. On the machines that were not part of the rollout yet, the update could be "force-discovered" by choosing *Check for Updates* from the Help menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Visual Studio Installer
1-Open the installer.
2-In the installer, look for the edition of Visual Studio that you installed.

[as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJFdv.jpg)