# How to update Visual Studio 2017 to latest release when VS is not showing it?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, updates

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and the version is 15.4.5.

This week Microsoft has released version 15.5 which has many feature that I need. For example, the Remoted iOS simulator for Windows.

The Visual Studio is neither showing the update notification message and nor showing in the Product updates section.

The only option I see is to download the latest version as offline installation and install it.

Is there a shortcut to update to 15.5?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694716/manually-update-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Thank you the response. That link was helpful. I used the update button to update to the latest version. If you respond to the question I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Why is this down voted? Visual Studio 2017 has new installation experience. As I am using for the first time it was confusing to me. I have already searched online before posting it here and there was no answer available readily. I am sure many people would have question.

Comment: BTW, if you into web api http development, 15.5-15.6 updates break what was working in 15.1-15.4. Namely, it has issues resolving references for dlls names `system.*` and `microsoft.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Sergey Vlasov the comments to my question above, the below answer in stackoverflow helped me. This is the only way to update Visual Studio if there is No notification message shown or the Update is not listed in the Product updates menu option inside Visual Studio 2017.

[Manually update Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694716/manually-update-visual-studio-2017)